# creating HTML5 application in windows moblie

Tags: html, windows-mobile

I need to create one sample HTML5 application in windows mobile. I want a good tutorial for that. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Windows Mobile (i.e. 6.5 or earlier) or Windows Phone?  There's a huge difference in the platforms and the answer depends on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed tutorial on creating HTML5 application for Windows phone [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/12/23/tutorial-how-to-create-html5-applications-on-windows-phone-thanks-to-phonegap.aspx)?

Comment: That's what I would have said as well.